# React. Input field with multivalues

Tags: user-interface, reactjs

How can I make or find react component input field with multivalues (really, don't know, how to call it), like tags when I ask question on stackoverflow.

[image]

So, I'd like to input one value, press enter, then put another value. Then get an array of submitted values in my form.

Comment: There is [so much on the web](https://react.parts/web?search=tags), please search for it before asking a question.

Comment: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Fabrian Schulz comment, chosen this one https://github.com/olahol/react-tagsinput.

To find it, I really need to write "tags input", even though I need it not for tag input.